# convert JSONobject value to Hash Map float value

Tags: java, android, json

I will apologize in advanced as I'm not familiar with this scenario. Is there a workaround in converting a JSONObject integer to be a float value in Hash Map? I'm creating this on android environment.

```
double value;

private Map<String, Float> getPricing() {
        final Map<String, Float> m = new HashMap<>();

        m.put("AAA", (float) value);
        m.put("BBB", 0.747049f);

        //remove some list to shorten the code

        return m;
    }

 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject jsonStore = json.getJSONObject("quotes");

                            value = jsonStore.getDouble("rack");
                        // just a replicate to check if JSON is not null when log or Toast
                            replicate = jsonStore.getDouble("rack");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("Response", "Error");
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("Response", "Error");
                }
            }
    );
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I log and Toast the JSONobject and verified it has a value but when it is converted to the float it returned 0. Any guidance is very much appreciated. Good day

Comment: It's 0 because it's the default value for a `double` in java. You add your `value` to the `Map` before setting a value for `value`

Comment: I tried before my post getting the value directly from the JSON as;

m.put("AAA", Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(value))); 

it was the same scenario, does your explanation means that on code structure, the value of the float is taken 1st before the value of any Json. Or there is something wrong in my coding, My apology as I'm blurred on this scenario. Thanks in advanced

Comment: Where do you call `getPricing()`? Can't you debug your code?